# On/Off native support in project by one click

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, native

My project has next structure:

- Java part for GUI
- Native part(C++) for logic

they are connected by socket.

So, in development process I run native part on desktop computer and java part in android device. They connect by WiFi and it is very comfortable to debug every part.
But sometimes I need build full and all-sufficient .apk where native part included in it as .so libs and calling from java code.

For this reason I try to find a handy way to "ON and OFF" native support in project. Now I see only one way - comment/uncomment all in Android.mk(it is important to prevent including .so libs in apk because they are big) and comment/uncomment call of native finction in java.

But I don't like it...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you describe looks like two different projects that share some (maybe much of) common code. You can easily have such setup in Eclipse, you can use linked folders to make source sharing between the two projects automatic. But it may be safer to use your source control's powers to maintain sync between sources for the two projects.

Comment: Alex yes, 2 projects looks like decision but I'm afraid it is very difficult to realize... But I will try, thank you

Comment: Feel free to ask for help if you find some steps difficult or suspicious.